# Azure Function not returning response through context.res

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to return a JSON object from Azure Function, and this examples, I mean, examples where response creation performing through **context.res** not working at all.

```
context.res = {
   body: {"name": "JSON STATHAM"}, //No. No mistake.
   contentType: 'application/json'
};
```

Why?

Only through **context.done** it's working if passed as a second parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at how your http output binding `name` property is specified. At one time our templates/samples were defaulting to using `$return` for the output binding name. Using `$return` that means the response is expected to be the **return value from the function**:

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "name": "req",
            "direction": "in",
            "methods": [ "get" ]
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "name": "$return",
            "direction": "out"
        }
    ]
}
```

In that mode, only the value returned via `context.done` (i.e. the function return value) will be used. Change `$return` to some other name of your choosing and you can use `context.res`.

Comment: I wish it wold be better documented. Thank you @mathewc.